# netbeans single java file not running

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to fetch some data from the db.
Below is the code is am trying to run but for some reason when I try to run the file, the netbeans notification says application deployed but still the file is not running.  I think I am missing some silly thing but cant figure it out.. need help!

```
class getDbData {

private final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private final String USER = "root";
private final String PASS = "";
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

public void getDbData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

}

public String[] getavailableMeasureMU() throws SQLException {
    String sql;
    sql = "Select * from availablemeasures where incentive=mu";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    String x = null;
    Vector data = new Vector();
    while (rs.next()) {

        data.add(rs.getString("measure"));
    }
    for (Object data1 : data) {
        System.out.println(data1);
    }

    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("called");
    getDbData call = new getDbData();
    try {
        call.getavailableMeasureMU();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

EDIT : Ran a simple code but still netbeans does nothing..

```
class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("test");
}
```

}

**EDIT** - ran above code in netbeans 8.0.2 but it did not run. However used the same code in 7.2 version and it runs.

Comment: are you tried right click, then run file

Comment: tried right click-> run file... tried run -> run file..  however when I run the whole web project its run fine.

Comment: try to restart Netbeans

Comment: did that too. :( still no luck.

Comment: are you tried clean.

Comment: clean and buildproject - notification says failed

Comment: Probably something in the environment, like you don't have the JDBC driver in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code works for  netbeans 8.0.2.
1 : In a package there should be a public class. So we made the class public in your code.
2 : Constructor do not have a return type not even void. In your code it was void.

```
public class getDbData {

private final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
private final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";   
private final String USER = "root";   
private final String PASS = "";   
    Connection conn;   
    Statement stmt;   
    ResultSet rs;   

public getDbData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);   
    stmt = conn.createStatement();   
}

public String[] getavailableMeasureMU() throws SQLException {   
    String sql;   
    sql = "Select * from availablemeasures where incentive='"+"mu"+"'";   
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);    
    String x = null;    
    Vector data = new Vector();    
    while (rs.next()) {    

        data.add(rs.getString("measure"));    
    }    
    for (Object data1 : data) {    
        System.out.println(data1);    
    }    

    return null;    

}

public static void main(String[] args){    
    System.out.println("called");     

    getDbData call = null;    
    try {    
        call = new getDbData();    
    } catch (SQLException ex) {     
        Logger.getLogger(getDbData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);     
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {     
        Logger.getLogger(getDbData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);    
    }    

    try {    
        call.getavailableMeasureMU();     
    } catch (Exception e) {     
        System.out.println(e);     
    }     
}
}
```

Comment: throws some exception but it does run in 7.2 however in 8.0.2 it does not

Comment: There is some issue with your system environment.  Plz try to run the code on some others system. Make sure that the latest jdk is installed and path is also set.

Put the jdbc driver in the correct path.
Table you have created should be in test schema or write the schema name before the table name.
Then try to run the code. If some issue exist ping the error

Comment: whats confusing to me is.. when i use the java file in my web app it gets me the correct output (after some exception handling)..  but its just when I run the file stand alone, it does nothing